# squash multiple historical commits

Tags: git, git-squash

I have an SVN history of some 20000 commits. I moved to Git and kept the history. Now i'm at 26000 commits, and I want to squash all commits from 1 to 20000.

- Initial commit: a4f5d18
- Migration to git: 5a42d81
- HEAD: 933eff

I tried checking out 20000 and rebasing:

```
git checkout 5a42d81
git rebase squash a4f5d18
```

But i get:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream squash
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your main branch looks like:

`master: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> .. -> 20000 -> A (First non migrated commit) -> B -> C -> ..`

And you'd like to get to:

`master: 1' (All your migrated commits) -> A' -> B' -> C' -> ..`

I think you could follow the approach of using `git rebase HEAD~26000 (first commit hash probably easier)` and changing `pick` to `squash`, but it might be fiddly/time consuming.

One potentially viable solution would be to create a new commit with the contents of your first 20000. Probably worth testing on a backup branch.

`git checkout <last migrated commit hash> -b backup-master`

```
backup-master: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> .. -> [20000] -> A (First non migrated commit) -> B -> C -> ..
                                       ^- you are here.
```

`git reset --soft <first migrated commit hash>`

```
backup-master: [1] -> 2 -> 3 -> .. -> 20000 -> A (First non migrated commit) -> B -> C -> ..
                ^- you are here         ^- the working directory tree/index reflects this commit
```

Amend your initial commit contents/message (or create a new commit if you'd prefer).

`git commit --amend`

Now `backup-master` should contain your squashed migration commits, let's move the new commits.

`git checkout master`

`git checkout -b master-rebase` (just in case we mess something up).

`git rebase backup-master` - I believe this will work because git is aware of the merges required to successfully rebase. If this works, you should be done, `master-rebase` will contain your desired result.

If this fails, you might have better success with `rebase --onto.`

`git rebase --onto <destination commit> <parent of first desired commit> <last desired commit>`

I.e.
`git rebase --onto backup-master <A>~1` master`

If this works it will place you on a commit that isn't currently on any branch, so you'll need to create one:

`git checkout -b rebase-success`.

A more thorough explanation of rebase --onto can be found [here](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120928/git-how-to-copy-a-range-of-commits-from-one-branch-to-another/).

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I was looking for, even although the actual rebasing isn't any faster and you don't get to see its progress unlike with the interactive rebase solution. NB: I had to create the branch after the soft reset since this resulted in a detached head state.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point, I'd overlooked that the `reset` step would leave you with a detached head. Updated the answer to add a `-b <branch>` to the initial checkout step.

Comment: @Chris I followed your approach and left with two histories at the end.  One runs from --root to master, another from --root to rebase-success.  Is this expected?

Comment: Hey, it's been a while since I answered this so I might have to get my head back in the game, what do you mean two histories? I think the intention was that you'd have a backup branch in case anything went wrong, but the successful rebase should be the one you're after.

Comment: @Chris let's say we start with one branch, the master, with 26000 commits.  After the series of operations, I was able to create a new branch rebase_successful which contains 6001 commits.  master still exists with 26000 commits.  How do I re-point master to this new branch and delete the original master?

Comment: Ah, it's getting a little outside the scope of this question at this point, as it's not exactly clear what your setup is. If it's just you working on a lone repo, you could delete the other `master` branch, and just create a new branch called master. Or you could checkout `master` and use `reset` to point the head at `rebase_successful` branch tip. If you're working with other's there's slightly more to consider (as you would be affecting shared history).

Answer (score 3):

How many commits you want retain, specify that number in the below command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6000
```

or more precisely

```
git rebase -i a4f5d18
```

Retain the 6000 commit from below( as pick) and change the rest of the `pick` to `squash`

if rebase succeeded

```
 git log
```

You can see all your commits squashes to one commit

and better you push the changes to remote, otherwise when you pull again you will see all commits.

```
git push -f
```

Comment: OP can just use `a4f5d18` in place of `HEAD~6000`.

Comment: @1615903 Thanks for sharing, it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into trouble with whitespaces, in all three scenarios (interactive rebase, soft reset, rebase onto). Git has the possibility of grafting branches, which developed into the replace function:

```
git replace -f 5a42d81 a4f5d18
git filter-branch
```